# Use both Dissect and Grok for a hybrid use case when a section of the line is reliably repeated, but the entire line is not

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elk, logstash-filter

I have the next textfile/logfile:

```
    2021-06-26 16:56:50,415 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/PowerCardv35' from server 'default-server'

2021-06-26 16:56:54,046 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'

2021-06-26 16:56:54,090 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

2021-06-26 16:56:54,356 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment v3_31-web.war (runtime-name: v3_31-web.war) in 314ms
 
2021-06-26 16:57:54,103 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

2021-06-26 16:59:32,862 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) 2021-06-26 16:59:32,858 INFO  [ServerService Thread Pool -- 93] serviceimpl.Pwc_time_zoneServiceImpl (Pwc_time_zoneServiceImpl.java:54) - PowerCardV3 : Operation:get_time_zone , USER : , SessionID :null , RemoteAddress:null
 
2021-06-26 16:59:32,887 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) jdbc/PWCCFGDS

2021-06-26 16:59:33,023 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) Database's time zone: +00:00

2021-06-26 16:59:33,025 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'spring'

2021-06-26 17:00:23,620 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/v3_31-web' for server 'default-server'

2021-06-26 17:06:56,923 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2021-06-26 17:06:56,922 INFO  [default task-1] serviceimpl.AuthentificationServiceImpl (AuthentificationServiceImpl.java:111) - PowerCardV3 : Operation authentificationService , USER :ISS001   

2021-06-26 17:07:05,313 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2021-06-26 17:07:05,311 INFO  [default task-1] serviceimpl.AuthentificationServiceImpl (AuthentificationServiceImpl.java:183) - PowerCardV3 : Authentication failed , USER :ISS001 , SessionID :hWayqQ7vMhUV4rOBvLCelwC8v0DIMLHb0X0u9vjX , RemoteAddress:172.18.0.1   

2021-06-26 17:07:05,689 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2021-06-26 17:07:05,683 ERROR [default task-1] errorhandling.BasicErrorHandlingAdvice (BasicErrorHandlingAdvice.java:94) - [org.fornax.cartridges.sculptor.framework.errorhandling.UnexpectedRuntimeException]  : Bad credentials

2021-06-26 17:07:05,690 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

2021-06-26 17:07:05,690 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)              at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93)

2021-06-26 17:07:05,696 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)              at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy293.authentificationService(Unknown Source)
```

I would like to display my index as a simple table. But in this use case we have a section of the line is reliably repeated, but the entire line is not.

To deconstruct the section of the line that is repeated, I used the Dissect filter like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/ahmed/Bureau/archive/dissect.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "message" => "%{date} %{time} %{loglevel} [%{package}]"
      }
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
  }
  stdout {}
}
```

But I don't know how I can use the Grok filter to process the remaining line values.

Any help please ? or any suggestion for my filter section?

if someone could write completely my filter section I would be very grateful. Because I'm just a beginner in ELK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends, what do you want to extract from your lines?

Comment: I want to extract any useful information. It is possible?

Comment: thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: it is possible, if you know in advance what you want to extract. Because what's "useful" will depends on your use case (ie why and what for are you collecting those logs)

Comment: This file is a jboss log. I want to extract informations that will allow me to simplify the anomaly detection of my java application deployed on jboss server. I want the anomaly, where is located and every detail about it.

Comment: Can you please suggest for me a grok filter? I'm stuck for 5 days, I can't advance in my project. I tried a lot of grok filters but no chance.

Comment: I don't know jboss so I don't know what 'anomaly' means or how I can find its location, but I could help you draft a filter if you indicate in your sample lines what you want to extract. Example: in the line 'foo bar dot.dash 9' I want to get the fields `field1=foo, field2=bar dot field3=9`